# How to access your composer application as a participant in single org application?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I created a composer supply chain application and whenever I run it using admin card on REST server and generated angular app with yeoman, I am accessing the network as admin user with the access to all the functionalities (creating users, assets or triggering all transactions).

**How can I access the network as one of the participant with the permissions that I defined in the .acl file?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should issue a new identity for the participant. This can be done using either the API, the command line, or by using ID cards in the Hyperledger Composer Playground.
See: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue

Then you should bind the identity created to be used by the participant to interact with the business network in the context of that participant.
See: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-bind

You can also enable the authentication to the rest server and then create and bind the cards for the authenticated user: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication

If you want to test it more easily and quickly you can do it via Hyperledger Composer Playground: click on the button on the top right (where you see 'admin') and then on ID registry. From this page you can now create and manage new identities.

Comment: does this code have to be written in script.js file along with other functionalities or somewhere else ?